# Get config value from file, or environment variable if file doesn't exist

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm trying to get a setting from a configuration file (preferably something simple like .ini or JSON, not XML). If the file or setting does not exist, I want to be able to fall back to retrieving an environment variable.

I'd prefer to use an existing library for working with JSON/INI and not parsing the file myself. However, most libraries I've found won't work if a file doesn't exist.

**How would I access a configuration value from a file that may or may not exist in F#?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to type providers, **[FSharp.Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/)** provides some basic parsers, including JSON. This allows you to do a runtime check using File.Exists and then parse using your preferred utility.

I took the following approach in FAKE:

```
if File.Exists "local.json" then 
    let localVarProps = JsonValue.Parse(File.ReadAllText"local.json").Properties
    for key, jsonValue in localVarProps do
        setEnvironVar key (jsonValue.AsString())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists) to test whether or not the file exists:

```
open System.IO

let getConfig file = 
    if File.Exists file
    then "config from file"
    else "config from somewhere else"
```

Comment: Thanks Mark - definitely aware of this approach, but the trick now is to get the config from the file. But I think I can't use the type providers from FSharp.Configuration because my code fails if the file is not there, even if I do a check to see if it exists.

Comment: If you want to use JSON, you could try [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), but why rule out XML? The built-in configuration system in .NET is based on XML files. It's far from perfect, but it's a mature and well-described system. With all its flaws, it still works adequately.

Answer (score 0):

[`OpenExeConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openexeconfiguration(v=vs.110).aspx) (despite it's name) can open an arbitrary config file.

There's also the [ASP.NET vNext Configuration](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration) stuff, [outlined in this article](http://whereslou.com/2014/05/23/asp-net-vnext-moving-parts-iconfiguration/) which is quite flexible - no idea how separable (or relevant to your actual use case) it is [aside from the fact that you could conditionally include the config file into the config manager depending on whether it exists a la Mark's answer].